# 3 way ANOVA, residuals not normally distributed

Tags: normal-distribution, anova, residuals

It has been a while since I have learnt about more complex stats and I am utterly stuck, not even sure I am using the right test at this point. 
I am trying to perform a 3 way analysis of variance using a general linear model. I have 3 independent variables (strain, metal exposure and temperature) and the dependant variable is a compound produced in response to those treatments. I am also looking at the effects of the interactions of the 3 independent variables. The residuals show equal variance as per Levene's test, P>0.05 but they are not normally distributed Anderson-Darling, P<0.05. How important is it that the residuals are normally distributed in this case.[image]

When I had the oral defence of my thesis the interviewers didn't question my stats (same independent variables but the dependant variable was a different compound, the residuals for that data were normally distributed and showed equal vatiance) but now I am questing everything as I am trying to expand on my results for publication. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: "the dependant variable is a compound produced in response to those treatments" -- presumably the value taken by the DV is a number of some kind. Do you mean "the amount of a compound", or something else?

Comment: Yes, the amount of compound

Comment: This quantity is necessarily non-negative and so you'd expect a skewed distribution (and one where variability was related to mean -- if you have no compound at all the variance would be 0, if you had hardly any compound the variance would tend to be small and if you had a lot of compound the variance would have more freedom to be a bit larger). I'd expect the relative error to be relevant rather than absolute error. At the same time, a linear model for the amount of compound doesn't make sense. I'd suggest considering either a gamma model with a log-link or a log-transformed response ... ctd

Comment: ctd... though theory (of your area, not mine) may suggest something else (e.g. perhaps transforming the predictors as well, or perhaps some more complex model for the mean)